# Conditional formula for adding text on range of rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have following data set of Cryptocurrency

[image]

I would like to show 0 or 1 in the comparison column for each row if the value in Open column is smaller or greater than the value in next field of same column .

For example -  if `(B2-B3 < 0 )`  then the corresponding field of second row in **Comparsion** column should be 0 , else 1 .

To keep it simple the highlighted red background should be 0 and White background should be 1 because the value in **Open** column is greater than its preceding value.

I need this data set to run my sample ML models .

Thanks

Comment: have you tried =IF(B2-B3<0,0,1)

Comment: @User91504 , first i selected the Comparison column and after that I used this formula . It is only adding 0 to first row of Comparison column

Comment: `=IF(IFERROR($B2-$B3<0;0)<0;0;1)` Just in case some formating is messed up, then drag it down

Comment: @dmb there is a formatting error . Also should i first select the whole comaprison columm ?  please help

Comment: @Softxide change the `;` for `,`, my locale format is latin so stuff is different. No you shoud type that at the first empty cell in comparison column, then drag the formula down.

Comment: @dmb i changed it to =IF(IFERROR($B2-$B3< ,0)<0,0,1) but it is still throwing error

Comment: @Softxide What error? Would you care to articulate on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71233/discussion-between-softxide-and-dmb).

Answer (score 1):

With the help of users in comment i was able to do this using =IF(B2-B3<0,0,1) as suggested by **User91504** and then dragging it as suggested by user **dmb**

Comment: you was nearly there yourself anyway :)

Comment: new to excel xD